# Breaking reopened class

Tags: ruby

In the example below I am reopening the `Module` class and setting instance variables. Can this possibly "break" the class if it already uses those instance variables for something else and how can this be avoided?

```
class Module
  def fields
    @fields ||= []
  end

  def foo name
    fields << name
  end
end
```

So far I haven't run into any issues with something similar to the above. However my next example shows how this could be a problem.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @test = 1   
  end

  def print
    puts @test  
  end
end

class Foo
  def oops
    @test = 2   
  end
end

obj = Foo.new

obj.bar
obj.print #=> 1

# method that we added later sets instance variable
obj.oops #=> 2
obj.print
```

This worries me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this possibly "break" the class if it already uses those instance
>   variables for something else and how can this be avoided?

```
1.9.3-p545 :003 > Module.new.instance_variables
 => [] 


1.9.3-p545 :004 > Module.new.instance_variable_defined? "@fields" => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example what will it change and what won't

```
module Helper
  @fields = '@fields defined in Helper'

  def self.print_helper_fields
    p @fields
  end

  def print
    p @fields
  end
end

class A
  include Helper

  attr_accessor :fields
end

class Module
  def foo
    @fields = '@fields changed in Module#foo'
  end
end

a = A.new
a.fields = [1, 2, 3]

a.print # => [1, 2, 3]
Helper.print_helper_fields # => '@fields defined in Helper'

Helper.foo

a.print # => [1, 2, 3]
Helper.print_helper_fields # => '@fields changed in Module#foo'
```